# Cron job for git pull

Tags: cron

I am using crontab to setup cronjob in order to pull from git, manually these commands work but from cronjob the seem not to:

> - - - - - cd /var/www/project/ && git pull

How can that be fixed?

Comment: I had a similar problem, for me the problem was crontab does not run under your profile, try loading that first. Eg, . . . . . /export/home/username/.profile; cd /var/www/project/ && git pull

Comment: I am a crontab newbie, please show what to do

Answer (score 5):

It's likely due to sudo permissions required on /var/.

Make a shell script *cron_pull.sh* anywhere and run it on cron.

In cron_pull.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/project
git pull
```

Run

```
sudo chmod +x cron_pull.sh
```

In sudo crontab -e:

```
* * * * * /path/to/cron_pull.sh
```

Comment: sorry, where do I make a cron_pull.sh?

Comment: seems that it's not working I have created a gitpull.sh in /var/www/project given permission in crontab added that line, but page is not updating therefore git pull hasn't been done

Comment: You have  to add this to "sudo crontab -e", not "crontab -e".

Fair warning, running commands that require sudo as a cronjob is generally a bad idea.

Comment: i did add it to sudo grontab -e  before saying it is not working, my other cronjobs do work fine